# How do I publish php source code to a local web server in rational team concert?

Tags: rtc, ibm-jazz, ibm-rational

I'll be using RTC in the near future here at work. My question is: where does it put the files the team members will be working on? I understand that each programmer will work on the projects files and they will push the changes to the main repository. We have a local web server where we test our work (php). So, do we have to configure RTC to publish the files to the web server? or the RTC server must be installed in the webserver so it can save the files?

Answer (score 4):

We use Rational Team Concert almost exactly as you describe, and it works brilliantly. My small team of web developers collaborates on website source code and delivers it to two different streams depending on its readiness: production-stream and staging-stream. Then we have defined two builds that check out the source code, move some things around, and push the files to the web servers via SCP. So, with a few clicks we kick off a staging build, watch it finish in about two minutes and everyone can see the changes on the staging server. When the code is ready for prime-time, the change sets are delivered to production-stream and the production build is kicked off, which is configured to copy the files to the production web server.

But even before a staging or production build is run, any of us can simply configure a local web server in RTC using the Eclipse PDE and Web Tools add-ons and see the site running in localhost as we develop.

All our work is done within Rational Team Concert, from planning, to bug tracking, to source control, to builds. It's very well-suited for website management.

Answer (score 3):

Your understanding is correct - you work on files locally, and they get uploaded on to the server when you checkin.  Bear in mind that checkin in RTC terms really means back-up your files to the server, it is a Deliver command that shares the files with others (it is worth a quick look at the articles on jazz.net that explains how SCM works).

One way to pubish to your php server is to make that part of a build, or a build in its own right (which RTC also handles - in conjunction with your favourite build tool).  The build would copy the files to the php server.  The advantage of doing this as a build is you will know exactly what versions of your files are being copied, and you will be able to reproduce this copy at any point in the future.

You do not need to install the RTC server on the php server.

You can also try posting on the forums on http://jazz.net/ if you have questions on RTC.

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

Another alternative would be to use the command line interface to accept all changes into a workspace and run that with a cron job.

To handle discarded change sets, you'd probably want to use something like:

```
scm workspace replace-components <workspace-name> stream <uuid-of-stream> --all
```

after you had initially loaded the workspace on your web server.